# Animate depending on screen resolution in expand aspect

Tags: godot

I have a mobile game that I deploy to multiple Android devices. I work on a resolution of 1080x1920. I am animating a label that comes from the bottom of the screen and stays close to the bottom to notify something to the player.

The problem is that it is not scale-dependent. I move it from y 2000 to y 1400, but if I am in a phone with a resolution of for example 1080x2000, the label is not placed in the same position relative to the bottom of the screen. If it is a tablet, it stretches sideways, and the label stops being centered. I use mode=canvas_items and aspect=expand, because I do not want a game with black borders.

Do you have a solution for this? Can I animate with anchors? Is there a better way to control the stretching of the screen?